# flutter::how is it possible replace the image with _showTopCard and the list with _buildListView (using silverappbar or anything else)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISqp2.png)

please help me ..how is it possible replace the image with card view and the list with ListView (using silverappbar or anything else)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visibility class.
It has a replacement attribute.
Its great that should work.
The code for it can be used like this:

```
Visibility(
  visible: bool_var,
  replacement: _showTopCard,
  child: image,
)
```

When `bool_var` is true, the `child` widget will be shown and when the `bool_var` is false the `replacement` widget will shown.
But make sure that you use widgets as the parameters for `replacement` and `child`

The official documentation is:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

And if you want to know more about this class in detail and how to use it in different ways, this link might help:
https://medium.com/@danle.sdev/widget-hide-and-seek-a-guide-to-managing-flutter-widgets-visibility-d7977cbaf444